# My OpenGraph action is not showing in the user's feed or activity log

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get my head around the Facebook's Opengraph API.

Where I'm up to:

- Actions and Object Types have been created
- The action has been approved
- I have publish_actions scope and the action is hooked up to the website (e.g.: http://tracker.thankyouwater.org/code/1400)
- I can view the news item representing the action by URL (e.g.: http://www.facebook.com/simonrobb/activity/10151135600251211). If I am logged in as another user, I can also view this news item.

However, the action doesn't show up on my feed/timeline or my activity log - as far as I can tell, the only way to view this action is by the URL as shown above.

Am I going crazy here? Why isn't the action even showing in my activity log?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: it should show. do you get an id back when you post the action?

Comment: yes I do, and I can use that id to view it at the URL http://www.facebook.com/simonrobb/activity/10151135600251211

Comment: the object should be on the same subdomain as the object. but you probably thought of that already. i would submit a bug report.

Comment: *the object should be on the same subdomain as the **event*

Comment: thanks for the help, Gil. I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: did you have any resolution for this? i m having the same problem.

Comment: @DarthVader in my case I found my problem was that opengraph collations don't seem to show up on pre-timeline Facebook. I upgraded to timeline and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - I found my problem was that opengraph collations don't seem to show up on pre-timeline Facebook. I upgraded to timeline and it worked fine.